# delphi, RESTServer Login and passowrd

Tags: rest, delphi, authentication, passwords

I create a RESTServer type application. (DataSnap WebBroker Application + HTTPS + certificate files)
When in the browser I call the function in the way

https://localhost:8080/DataSnap/rest/TServerMethods/reversestring/sometext

then appears small window for entering login and password. Additionally, in the DSAuthenticationManager.OnUserAuthenticate event, I can check login and password.

But the server also has the ability to create actions. I made an action /Reversestring , and if I call it

https://localhost:8080/reversestring/sometext

then function is executed but the login and password are not checked.
How to check a login in the second case?

Comment: Did you terminate the web browser between tests? Basic auth credentials will be stored until the browser is closed.

Comment: Yes, I did. And also breakpoint in OnUserAuthenticate event is not execute in the second way.

Comment: how do you create "actions" (with which Delphi component / library)? From the second URL it seems to be not managed by DataSnap, even if it is the same port (8080)

Comment: how do I create actions? WebModule.Actions property